# Implement convolution in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I have a equation that used to compute `sigma`, in which i is index from `1 to N`,`*` denotes convolution operation, Omega is image domain.

[image]

I want to implement it by matlab code. Currently, I have three options to implement the above equation. Could you look at my equation and said to me *which one is correct?* I spend so much time to see what is differnent amongs methods but I could not find. Thanks in advance

The different between Method 1 and Method 2 that is method 1 compute the sigma after loop but Method 2 computes it in loop.

```
sigma(1:row,1:col,1:dim) = nu/d;
```

**Does it give same result?**

*===========Matlab code==============*

**Method 1**

```
     nu = 0;
     d = 0;
     I2 = I.^2;
     [row,col] = size(I);
      for i = 1:N
          KuI2 = conv2(u(:,:,i).*I2,k,'same');
          bc = b.*(c(:,:,i));
          bcKuI = -2*bc.*conv2(u(:,:,i).*I,k,'same');
          bc2Ku = bc.^2.*conv2(u(:,:,i),k,'same');

          nu = nu + sum(sum(KuI2+bcKuI+bc2Ku));
          ku = conv2(u(:,:,i),k,'same');
          d = d + sum(sum(ku));
      end
      d  = d + (d==0)*eps; 
      sigma(1:row,1:col,1:dim) = nu/d;
```

**Method 2:**

```
  I2 = I.^2;
  [row,col] = size(I);
  for i = 1:dim
      KuI2 = conv2(u(:,:,i).*I2,k,'same');
      bc = b.*(c(:,:,i));
      bcKuI = -2*bc.*conv2(u(:,:,i).*I,k,'same');
      bc2Ku = bc.^2.*conv2(u(:,:,i),k,'same');
      nu = sum(sum(KuI2+bcKuI+bc2Ku));
      ku = conv2(u(:,:,i),k,'same');
      d =  sum(sum(ku));
      d  = d + (d==0)*eps;
      sigma(1:row,1:col,i) = nu/d;
  end
```

**Method 3:**

```
  I2 = I.^2;
  [row,col] = size(I);
  for i = 1:dim
      KuI2 = conv2(u(:,:,i).*I2,k,'same');
      bc = b.*(c(:,:,i));
      bcKuI = -2*bc.*conv2(u(:,:,i).*I,k,'same');
      bc2Ku = bc.^2.*conv2(u(:,:,i),k,'same');

      ku = conv2(u(:,:,i),k,'same');
      d  = ku + (ku==0)*eps;
      sigma(:,:,i) = (KuI2+bcKuI+bc2Ku)./d;
  end
  sigma = sigma + (sigma==0).*eps;
```

Comment: You can not implement the equation because it's continuous. Unless you use symbolic, you are always stuck in the discrete world. So, convert it to discrete form first.

Comment: It is converted yet by using convolution. Let see equation 24 in http://www.math.gsu.edu/~xye/papers/ZYC13_Seg_TIP.pdf or 21 in http://kaihuazhang.net/J_papers/tcyb2014a.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think that Method 1 is assume that `sigma1=sigma2=...sigman` because you were computed out of loop function

```
sigma(1:row,1:col,1:dim) = nu/d;
```

where nu and d are cumulative sum for each iteration.

While, the Method 2 shown that `sigma1 !=sigma 2 !=..sigman` because each sigma is calculated in loop function

Hope it help